# Is there a way to hide link prefixes in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, font-lock, org-link, text-properties, compose-region

For some link types it would be nice to hide the link prefix automatically. [This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/zzflhf/comment/j2oe7ck/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) does this with text properties, but I'd prefer if it was possible to do with something like prettify-symbols or compose region. The closest I got was...

```lisp
(defun my/activate-link (start end path bracketp &optional icon)
  "Compose icons before links"
  (save-excursion
    (if org-descriptive-links
        (compose-region start (1+ start) (concat icon " "))
      (org-link-apply-face start end)
      )
    ))

(org-link-set-parameters "menu" :activate-func (lambda (start end path bracketp) (my/activate-link start end path bracketp "\uf0c9")))
```

I realize this is only fontifying the first two characters of the link. I want to add in a `keyword` parameter to the arguments list of the function, but that I don't know how to get compose region to find the beginning and end of that keyword.